# Ansible does not recognize default inventory set in config

Tags: ansible

I can use my Ansible inventory file to ping all hosts if I specify it explicity:

```
ansible -i mmp_default/mmp_static_default  all -m ping

mmp-websockets002.prod01.company.com | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
mmp-staticweb001.prod01.company.com | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
```

But setting it up as a default inventory in my config doesn't work:

```
ansible all -m ping
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

This is my config:

```
sudo cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
ansible_managed = This file is managed by Merlin. Do not edit directly.
deprecation_warnings = False
timeout=30
remote_user = centos
private_key_file = /home/centos/AWS.pem

[privilege_escalation]
become=True
become_user=root

[inventory]
## enable inventory plugins, default: 'host_list', 'script', 'yaml', 'ini'
enable_plugins = auto, ini
inventory = /home/centos/R2.4.1/merlin/mmp_default/mmp_static_default
```

I have my inventory listed as: `inventory = /home/centos/R2.4.1/merlin/mmp_default/mmp_static_default`

Why doesn't ansible recognize the inventory file I setup in the config?

Comment: try defining the inventory file from `inventory` section to `defaults` section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-host-list), `inventory` setting should be in defaults section:

```
[defaults]
...
inventory = /home/centos/R2.4.1/merlin/mmp_default/mmp_static_default
...

[privilege_escalation]
....
```